# syntax error near unexpected token `date=`echo $1|cut -d"." -f1-3`'

Tags: bash

I wrote this function many times, but can't get it right..looks like a small syntax error, but cant fix it.

```
    function hadleDate{
    date=`echo $1|cut -d"." -f1-3`
    for element in $date; do
        size=${#element} 
        if [[ $element == 0? ]]; then
            echo -n $element|cut -c2-
        elif [[ $size -eq 4 ]]; then 
            echo $element
        else
            echo -n $element
        fi
    done
}
mos="14.03.2013"
echo handleDate $mos
```

Comment: Can you post your efforts after attempting couple of things? 1. Add a line `set -x` in the beginning of your script and run to see what could have been the source of the problem 2. Copy paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors warning(s) seen.

Comment: Also change typo: Not hadle... but handle...

Answer (score 4):

The function name in the declaration can't be followed by `{` directly. There should be whitespace or parentheses.

```
function hadleDate () {
#                  ~~
```

Comment: They are optional with the `function` keyword, but the space before the `{` is not.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, reworded.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to visit shellcheck.net for syntax errors.

You missed, fi for if and done for "for"

```
 function hadleDate {
    date=`echo $1|cut -d"." -f1-3`
    for element in $date; do
        size=${#element}
        if [[ $element == 0? ]]; then
            echo -n $element|cut -c2-
        elif [[ $size -eq 4 ]]; then
            echo $element

        fi
    done
    }
    mos="14.03.2013"
    echo handleDate $mos
```

Comment: Most relevantly, he forgot the space between `hadleDate` and `{`.

Comment: yes, indeed. Bottom line is Shellcheck should be done before posting here :)

Comment: sorry guys, I am a newbe here, still learning how to work here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your handleDate function tries to cut the date in fields and put them in an array. Your variable date is not an array but just a string.
You can do without an array like this:

```
function handleDate {
   # Cut fields with dots and use $1 as input for the read.
   IFS=. read mm dd yyyy <<< "${1}"
   # Using printf can cut of the zeroes by converting the string to a number
   printf "%d-%d-%s\n" "${mm}" "${dd}" "${yyyy}"
}

mos="14.03.2013"
handleDate "${mos}"
```